# Practical Implementation of Smith predictor

Tags: control, control-system

I am now dealing with Smith predictor and I understand that it's based on model of the controlled plant. This model I can get by some identification method, but such a model will never be absolutely precise. Thus I have following question: How can I provide, that my model won't diverge with the reality? Would it be possible to use some "corrective" term based on comparison between actual plant output and estimated plant output? Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is called recursive least squares estimator (RLS), then RLS with forgeting factor - which lets also to forget/update the estimated parameters. The system order num/denum has to be known "a priori", also the dead time

There are some other more efficient algorithms like AUDI-LS augmented UD identification, it has a multi-model information of the system, means you have multiple models with various num/denum, you then need to use some other technique to reject and take only the right model.

The problem is that I had not found any algortihm that can estimate a real plant with unknown order, dead time to give me the exact estimation parameters. The problamitic is of course dead time. Morevoer, if the dead time changes how would you update the Smith predictor?

You can find AUDI algorithm implemented here: http://www.tij.co.jp/jp/lit/an/spra311/spra311.pdf but other stuf doesn't work for me, like generalized predictive controller. 
For RLS you will find many algorithms on the net.

EDIT:
http://www.ualberta.ca/dept/chemeng/ftp/pub/OUTGOING/Audi/infoforget.ps
http://www.ualberta.ca/dept/chemeng/ftp/pub/OUTGOING/Audi/close.ps
http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:315781/FULLTEXT02
http://arrow.dit.ie/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1048&context=engscheleart

Download above papers, and look into a implemented code, you will find some implemented update constraints. Also it is explained how to retreive the estimated model with closest order, you need to compare loss functions data. Then you will also find some information how to extract dead time by overparametrization (order) of estimated function. I have rewritten the AUDI in MS visual C and I have to admit it was quite good, until I had to implement dead time recognition with overparametrization by myself (the source code doesen't detect the dead time), then I gave up.

If your dead time is known a priori and stable, you can use some of these techiques like RLS, Bierman UD, and AUDI by delaying the system output response vector, while calculating. RLS goes soon away if you don't have double precision float on your platform, while this AUDI is quite stable.

Let me know if you have done something.

Answer (score 0):

The effect described in your question in connection with smith predictor applications is known as "model mismatch". There are several techniques to compensate for this with self-tuning correction algorithms. You can find an example on basis of a fuzzy logic regulator in the following paper: [A New Smith Predictor for Control of Processes with Long Time Delays](http://onlinepresent.org/proceedings/vol77_2014/19.pdf). Please see also the references in the end of the paper for further studies.